# g-wan: building library outside of /csp, and g++ compilation problems

Tags: include, g++, pragma, g-wan

I am giving Gwan a whirl.

Having made it through example code, I started a small project with more than one source file. I now have two problems:

1. I got a linking error at server startup:

   Linking main.cpp: undefined symbol: _ZN7GwanUrl9concatAllEv

(the main file #includes the two other files; all the files are in the csp directory)

1. As an alternative to having all the files in the /csp directory, I would like to make a library outside of the /csp directory while still using some of the gwan functions. sadly, a tonne of errors follow -- WHEN I GCC from commandline not via G-WAN Startup.

   In file included from /home/ec2-user/gwan/include/gwan.h:22,
                    from Xbufstream.h:10,
                    from Xbufstream.cpp:10:
   /usr/include/time.h:199: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   .....

Anyone knows what the gwan g++ argument string looks like?

(odd the 1. and 1. its 1. and 2. in the editor)

Comment: Still not getting it. I do want to use G-WAN symbols. For example, lets say i want to: 
    `Xbufstream& Xbufstream::operator<<(const char& c) {
 xbuf_xcat(xbuffer, "%c", c);
 return *this;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not a linker issue: you have `"undefined symbol"` rather than `"unresolved symbol"` as an error.

This is simply an `#include` issue.

1. define the main() function in your script.cpp file.
2. there's a G-WAN folder dedicated to user-defined include files called `/gwan/include` but you can as well use /csp/my_include.hpp... if you are using the right syntax:

For example, having `#include "toto.hpp"` in /csp/hello.cpp lets me reach C++ functions *defined and implemented* in the `gwan/include/toto.hpp` file (or *defined in toto.hpp and implemented in a pre-compiled library* linked to your script with #pragma link).

If you rather use `#include <toto.hpp>` then the SYSTEM INCLUDE PATH will be searched instead (and this will work providing that your library was correctly installed).

If you want to use `#include "toto.hpp"` for a custom folder that was not setup in the system, you can use G-WAN's `#pragma include "../my_folder"` directive to specify its PATH or you can explicitely specify it in each include: `#include "../my_folder/toto.hpp"`.

Nothing fancy there, only C/C++ dependancy rules apply (and G-WAN really helps by providing alternate ways that do not involve system settings).

For libraries (see the G-WAN examples for SQLite, Cairo, mySQL, cURL, etc.) you can either use pre-installed libraries that exported their location in SYSTEM variables... or put your library in the `/gwan/libraries` folder and their include file in the `/gwan/include` folder.

When writing your own libraries, remember that they need to be pre-compiled. This means that you obviously cannot use G-WAN symbols since your compiler may #include "gwan.h" (to have the definitions) but your linker will not know from where G-WAN symbols can be found. The way around is to always use the G-WAN API from the G-WAN scripts. Your custom libraries must either be general-purpose or buffer any payload intended to be used by G-WAN. No-double copy is needed since G-WAN provides the `set_reply()` call to let G-WAN use *persistent* replies built without the `reply xbuffer` provided by G-WAN servlets.

Now, a last word about `linking` (which was not the cause of your trouble but could participate to the confusion). If you mix C and C++, use `extern C {}` to wrap your C++ prototypes called from C (otherwise you will *really* have `"unresolved symbols"`).

With all this information, you should be ready to face every possible situation.

Comment: Hi Gil. Thanks for the #include tips. Specifying PATHs can be confusing to deal with at times.

Comment: I use GWAN's JSON and KV store calls in my library. The trick is to use function pointers and initialize them to the corresponding GWAN calls inside a GWAN C script. Good thing with this approach is the library may not rely on GWAN and can fall back to some other JSON or KV store implementation if necessary.

Comment: Ogla, the function pointers initialization (a sophisticated approach for advanced users) is best implemented in the int() call of a conection handler (this is executed once in the life of the server).

Comment: @Gil thanks for the response. And excuse the late response; its Xmas.
By the above logic `#include "toto.hpp"` looks in the script directory, `csp`. (without `"../my_folder"` )
Or maybe `#pragma include "."`
At any rate, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

the issue of referencing gwan.h symbols inside #include files can also be *solved* by moving all code into the header file, whether its .h or .hpp

its ungraceful but a fix nevertheless. and good enough for the simple extension i wanted.

looking into the /libraries/sqlite3/sqlite.h helped.

@gil, thanks for your time.